# SparkSQL ,Spark DataFrame : batch rename csv headers

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to change headers of a very large csv file .

I use SparkSQL

All headers have `some_string` in each header name , like `some_string.header_name`

My Spark configuration `conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("readCSV")`

To read csv file I use `com.databricks.spark.csv package`

```
   logs_df = sqlContext.load(
   source = "com.databricks.spark.csv",
   header = 'true',
   inferSchema ='true',
   path = 'my_file.csv'
)
```

my code

```
 header = logs_df.first()
 schemaString = header.replace('`some_string.`','')
```

produce error :

```
  AttributeError                            
  Traceback (most recent call last)
  <ipython-input-63-ccfad59fc785> in <module>()

   1255             raise AttributeError(item)
   1256         except ValueError:
-> 1257             raise AttributeError(item)
   1258 
   1259     def __setattr__(self, key, value):

AttributeError: replace
```

I don't like to use `logs_df.withColumnRenamed()` because I have more then 200 columns

**Very appricciate for any idea how to change headers fast and effectively**

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Python enough to give you a sample code snippet. Hope this might give you some hints for Python...
Option 1: I may suggest to do this using RDD and building the schema using reflection (http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#inferring-the-schema-using-reflection). 
 In scala, I would use a case class to reflect this thru.
One issue with RDD may be pertaining to its performance.

Option 2: Another option may be to use DataFrame.toDF(colNames: String*): DataFrame. Basically arrange / select the columns in the right order you would like and provide the column names using a sequence built programatically.

Hope this helps.